# JIB is not able to detect docker credentials

Tags: spring, docker, jhipster, jib

I am building a generated app whith Jhipster.
I run the command to build the images and run the app containerized. I started Docker Desktop on windows 11.

To remind, this is the command: `./gradlew -Pprod bootJar jib`
The output after a while is :

```
Execution failed for task ':jib'.
> com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.BuildStepsExecutionException: Build image failed, perhaps you should make sure your credentials for 'registr
y-1.docker.io/library/app2' are set up correctly. See https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-should-i-do-when-the-registry-responds-with-unauthorized for help
```

I tried multiple times to log in on docker:

```
docker login registry-1.docker.io
```

The login is **successful** and the `config.json` of docker content is:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {},
        "registry-1.docker.io": {}
    },
    "credsStore": "desktop"
}
```

I'm sure that this is where `JIB`, by default looks for docker creds, but I can not see any creds here. It looks like the credentials are stored somewhere else, here is the version of Docker: `Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try building offline first, probably a permission issue on the remote repository, which will need to be fixed on hub.docker.com